# How can I change the order of keys in a NSDictionary

Tags: cocoa, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a mutable array that consist of array of dictionaries as:

```
(
      {
        A = Mango;
        B = "John";
        C = SLOVAKIA;
        D = 01/27/13;
        E = 2000;
    },
        {
        A = Banana;
        B = "Johny";
        C = THAILAND;
        D = 02/27/13;
        E = 4000;
    },
        {
        A = Orange;
        B = "Lezin";
        C = US;
        D = 03/27/13;
        E = 6000;
    }
)
```

Now I want to sort the array based on the keys so that the order of the keys become BECAD which is neither ascending nor descending order,it is a random order.
Expected output is as follows:

```
(
      {
        B = "John";
        E = 2000;
        C = SLOVAKIA;
        A = Mango;
        D = 01/27/13;
    },
        {
        B = "Johny";
        E = 4000;
        C = THAILAND;
        A = Banana;
        D = 02/27/13;
    },
        {
        B = "Lezin";
        E = 6000;
        C = US;
        A = Orange;
        D = 03/27/13;
    }
)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: A dictionary is a kind of data structure where order makes no sense... You just access elements by key, so why do you want order at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no inherent order to dictionary keys guaranteed. In practice, they appear to be FILO order. But it's an implementation detail.

You should use a proxy like NSArrayController to get sorting you want.

Answer (score -1):

NSMutableDictionary always returns keys in a disordered manner.

If we really want to maintain order then we may need to  add 01, 02 ,03 Serial Numbers before/after the Keys to sort them in the order we want to put it and then we need to trim the numeric part of the String and use it.